# Why Angular 2 does not see a dynamically created selector?

Tags: javascript, angular

This is start-page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>document.write('<base href="/app/" />');</script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>App</title>
</head>
<body>

<my-app>
    Loading...
</my-app>

<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
<!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
<script src="/cp/node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="/cp/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="/cp/node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>

<script src="/cp/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="/cp/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="/cp/node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="/cp/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="/cp/node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
<script src="/cp/node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>

<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script>
    System.config({
        packages: {
            app: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
    System.import('app/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This component (`startComponent`) loads the root page of the application:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/mainPage.html',
    directives: [RouterOutlet,RouterLink,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        HTTP_PROVIDERS
    ]
})
```

The page `mainPage.html` contains:

```
<div id="content">
    <a [routerLink]="['NextPage']">NextPage</a>
    <my-content></my-content>
</div>
```

When we go to the link `NextPage`, init this component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-content',
    templateUrl: 'app/nextPage.html'
})

export class NextPageComponent implements OnInit {
    public str = "";

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getStr();
    }

    getStr(){
        this.str = "abc";
    }
}
```

`NextPageComponent` should insert a line "abc" to the selector `my-content` which was created by a component of `startComponent`. 
But somehow, he inserts `abc` line at the end of the selector `my-app`, not `my-content`.

That is, in the end we get the following page:

```
<my-app>
    <div id="content">
        <a [routerLink]="['NextPage']">NextPage</a>
        <my-content></my-content>
    </div>
    <my-content _ngcontent-quv-2=""><div>abc</div></my-content>
</my-app>
```

But, I want get such a page in result:

```
<my-app>
    <div id="content">
        <a [routerLink]="['NextPage']">NextPage</a>
        <my-content><div>abc</div></my-content>
    </div>
</my-app>
```

Why this is happening? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because that's how Router works. It loads components dynamically. The selector you set in you routing component won't match anything on the view, it will dynamically push the component in the view.

Comment: @EricMartinez I do not quite understand. You can give a detailed answer with an example?

Comment: sanu, I added an answer, I hope it clarifies how Router works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Router](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/Router-class.html) internally uses [DynamicComponentLoader](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html) (see [Router's source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-beta.8/modules/angular2/src/router/router_outlet.ts#L65)) to instantiate Components dynamically (the name pretty much says it).

It uses specifically `loadNextToLocation` and the docs state

> loadNextToLocation(...)
>
> Creates an instance of a Component and attaches it to the View Container found at the location specified as ElementRef.

As you see it attaches the Component into the view. It doesn't check the view to see if it matches something inside of it, so whether you have some element that matches the selector it won't work because, again, Router it's not looking for anything on the view, it's attaching the Component in the view, in other words it's pushing it.

Let's try that behavior ourselves. Let's put in some component's view some elements that matches some dynamic component selector

```js
@Component({
  selector : 'dynamic-cmp',
  template : 'Dynamic template'
})
class DynamicCmp {}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template : `
    <dynamic-cmp></dynamic-cmp>    <!-- Element matching DynamicCmp selector -->
    <dynamic-cmp></dynamic-cmp>    <!-- Element matching DynamicCmp selector -->
  `
})
export class App {
  constructor(private _dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, private _eRef: ElementRef) {}
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this._dcl.loadNextToLocation(DynamicCmp, this._eRef);
  }
}
```

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xjtHWF3HU8mfUZL225BR?p=preview) with the example above

*Note : I'm not adding DynamicCmp in directives property*

When you run that example and see the DOM you'll see this

```
<my-app>
    <dynamic-cmp></dynamic-cmp>
    <dynamic-cmp></dynamic-cmp>
</my-app>
<dynamic-cmp _ngcontent-ybo-2="">Dynamic template</dynamic-cmp>
```

There are two empty `dynamic-cmp` elements even when they match the dynamic component's selector.

This is exactly what Router does, and that's why you see this behavior. Router doesn't rely on the view (it doesn't look for matching selectors) nor in directives, it loads components dynamically (push them) into the view specified.

I hope this clarifies a little bit what's happening.

Comment: Thank you very much! If you are not difficult, you can make your example with the correct result? (p.s. I recently started studying angular, and I want to study the case as a whole)

Comment: @sanu0074 what would be the correct result for you in this case?

Comment: For example, that the result was:`<my-app>
    <dynamic-cmp></dynamic-cmp>
    <dynamic-cmp>Dynamic template</dynamic-cmp>
</my-app>`

Comment: @sanu0074 here's another [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/kY5DP0fxDxX0BQYVROgS?p=preview) using `loadIntoLocation`. This will put it inside `my-app` but outside the container, and that's just how it works so don't be surprise.

Comment: Take a look at this code: https://plnkr.co/edit/DsDpXG72bjpyaWfPc1S0?p=preview `LocalizationComponent` downloading content in to `fx-app` selector. And it is necessary that in `fx-content`. I can not understand. You can look at the code? (p.s. Itself an example plunker will not work because it lacks the files. Just look at the code.)

Comment: @sanu0074 your initial question is exactly what you're asking right now and I just answered... if you want Router content inside `<div container></div>` you should add RouterOutlet to it : `<div class="container"><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>`

Comment: Thank you very much! You better:) I did not know about what makes `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`